# VBA Excel - Update Cell value based on other cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a formula in a  Range of cells based on other range cells values from another worksheet. The formula is shown below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:G43").Formula = "=Worksheets("1ºperíodo").Range("V14:V43").Value"
```

But the code doesn't work and I get a syntax error. That must be related with the strings but I don't know how to fix it. 
The value  at `V14` must be equal to the value at `G14` until the last cell, i.e., the value at `G14` equals the value at `V43`. Besides the syntax error   is the formula correct based on what I expect to have?

Comment: Try this: `=Worksheets(""1ºperíodo")".Range(""V14:V43"").Value"`, assuming the worksheet name is correct with no typos. (In formulas, you need to double up on quotes. Otherwise VBA thinks you're at the end of the `.Formula` statement.)

Comment: @BruceWayne I think you've got a typo at the end of that first parenthesis Bruce, should be `"")`

Comment: @BruceWayne I get a runtime error '1004' using that. I already tried that before.

Comment: D'oh, sorry about the typo - good catch @dwirony.  Try `...Formula = "=Worksheets(""1ºperíodo"").Range(""V14:V43"").Value"`.  OP can you confirm that the worksheet name is literally `1ºperíodo`? (No space, has the accented `i`, and the degree symbol)?  Also, what error do you get exactly?  Finally, what are you trying to do? You're using a `.Formula` to set the `Value`? That's not a formula AFAIK. Do you mean perhaps `...Formula = "=Worksheets(""1ºperíodo"").Range(""V14"").Value"`?  Clarifying what you're trying to do will help greatly.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes the worksheet name is exactly that one. 'Application- defined or object-defined error'. I want that G14 cell contains the formula =V14 until reach the G43 cell =V43.

Comment: @PedroR. That formula isn't valid. You couldn't type that formula into a cell without excel stopping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"=Worksheets("1ºperíodo").Range("V14:V43").Value"`

is not a formula.  It is a value.

If you only want the static values then just assign the values:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:G43").Value = Worksheets("1ºperíodo").Range("V14:V43").Value
```

If you want a live formula you need to pull vba from the string and use the .Address function:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:G43").Formula = "=" & Worksheets("1ºperíodo").Range("V14").Address(0,0,,1)
```

But the above can be simplified to:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("G14:G43").Formula = "='1ºperíodo'!V14"
```

With the formula, we only need to refer to the first cell with a relative reference and vba will make the changes to each row.

Comment: @PedroR. them please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.